# pandas sqrt and roots do not work and yield NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math.sqrt

I have dataframe with two numerical float values.
I want to do some math based on those columns values to calculate new columns.

those are the calculation I want to do:

```
df['calc1']=(df['col1']**(0.5))/(df['col2']**2)

df['calc2']=(df['col1']**(df['col2']))/(df['col2']**(df['col1']))
```

The problem is that those calculations create NaN values.
I have tried to use sqrt :

```
(np.sqrt((df['col1']))/(df['col2']**2))
```

but that also created NaN.
I also tried to change the 0.5 to 1/2 but the same.

What do I do wrong?

edit: example:

```
>>>col1    col2
0  -6.14   -15.12
1  -6.12   -7.9
2  -6.12   -7.94
...
```

Comment: do you have negative numbers in col1 ?

Comment: pls post sample data

Comment: @StupidWolf yes, there are negative numebrs....now makes sense...

Comment: yeah.. i think you need to sort that out first